# passing radio buttons from javascript to django views as a paramater

Tags: php, python, html, django

I have a html page where I am passing the selected checkboxes to django views as parameter which works completely fine.

layout.html

```
<form action="{% url 'URL Which calls view' %}" method="post">
{% csrf_token %}
<label class="checkbox">
  <input type="checkbox" name="checks" value="REG_AGREED_SUITE01">REG_AGREED_SUITE01
  </label>
   <hr>
  <label class="checkbox">
  <input type="checkbox" name="checks" value="REG_AGREED_SUITE02">REG_AGREED_SUITE02
  </label>
   <hr>
  <label class="checkbox">
  <input type="checkbox" name="checks" value="REG_AGREED_SUITE03">REG_AGREED_SUITE03
  </label>
   <hr>
```

form.py

```
class NameForm(forms.Form):
```

views.py

```
def view(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
    form = NameForm(request.POST)
    else:
    form = NameForm()
    print request.POST.getlist('checks')

    form = NameForm(request.POST)
    list1 = request.POST.getlist('checks')
    TestSuite = ', '.join(list1)
```

Now I have a situation, Where I would like to pass the radio buttons as parameters in django views. I have a json file from which using java script I am pulling the values and displaying on html. Is there any way, when ever I select a radio button, I can pass them as a parameter in django views as above case? or is it the best approach to create a form in Django?

temp.json

```
[
    {"STBStatus": "1", "RouterSNo": "R1", "STBLabel": "STB#1", "STBSno": "M11435TDS144"},
    {"STBStatus": "1", "RouterSNo": "R1", "STBLabel": "STB#2", "STBSno": "M11543TH4292"},
    {"STBStatus": "0", "RouterSNo": "R1", "STBLabel": "STB#3", "STBSno": "SN005"},
    {"STBStatus": "1", "RouterSNo": "R1", "STBLabel": "STB#4", "STBSno": "M11509TD9937"},
    {"STBStatus": "1", "RouterSNo": "R1", "STBLabel": "STB#5", "STBSno": "M11543TH4258"},
    {"STBStatus": "0", "RouterSNo": "R1", "STBLabel": "STB#6", "STBSno": "SN005"},
    {"STBStatus": "0", "RouterSNo": "R1", "STBLabel": "STB#7", "STBSno": "SN006"},
    {"STBStatus": "0", "RouterSNo": "R1", "STBLabel": "STB#8", "STBSno": "SN007"}
]
```

Javascript:

```
<script>

 function stbststus(){
  show_alert()
    $.getJSON("Json", function(result){
        $("#STBStatus").empty();
          $.each(result, function(i, item){
            if(item.STBStatus == "1"){
              colorclass = "available"
            }
            if(item.STBStatus == "0"){
              colorclass = "offline"
            }
            if(item.STBStatus == "2"){
              colorclass = "In use"
            }
              $("#STBStatus").append("<label class='radio'><input type='radio' name='optradio'  class='optradio'>"+item.STBLabel +"   <i class='fa fa-circle pull-right  "+colorclass+"' aria-hidden='true'></i></label> <hr>");
          });
      });
 }
</script>
```

layout.html

```
  <div class="quote-text scroller" id="STBStatus"> </div> 

<div class="wrapper">
 <div class="buttonHolder" onclick="pageload()">
<p><a href="Set_Top_Box" class="btn btn-primary btn-large">Get Settopbox Status &raquo;</a></p>
```

Answer (score 0):

Django will not handle onClick events or anything of sort, you are better off with javascript and or jquery for that.

**Jquery**

```
$(function(){
  $('input[type="radio"]').click(function(){
    if ($(this).is(':checked'))
    {
      alert($(this).val());
    }
  });
});
```

or for vanilla JavaScript check this url [Get Value of Selected Radio Button](http://www.dyn-web.com/tutorials/forms/radio/get-selected.php).